# The ellipsis character in a code block looks like an underscore

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

The ellipsis character in a code block resembles an underscore: `…` vs. `_`

It would be nicer if it was shown more clearly as three separate dots, as it is the case in the non-code text ("…" vs. "...").

---

To reply to Nathan Tuggy's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280842/the-ellipsis-character-in-a-code-block-looks-like-an-underscore#comment912083_280842) that it's just the natural consequence of fitting an unusually wide glyph (ellipsis) into a monospace font, here is an example of an ellipsis character in a monospace font where the three dots are much more distinguishable:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. What ellipsis character? Who is adding it? Can you post a screenshot please?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, [U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm)

Comment: @Franck, I can't see how this would be adjustable outside of changing the font. It's a single glyph. Unless you propose an automated text substitution, replacing the single code point with three, which is an absolutely horrible idea in source code.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You brought back a really bad memory. Once, I wrote some code in one IDE, and when I copied it over to another IDE it broke without warning. I spent a few hours trying to figure it out and I realized that `...` was transformed to `…`

Comment: Well as @Josh said, it doesn't make sense to use whole different font for a single character, or replacing the character with something else. It's the OP responsibility to check the code after posting, and if something look wrong, fix it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I don't know, I am not familiar with SE code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SE; it's just the natural consequence of fitting an unusually wide glyph (ellipsis) into a monospace font. There is no solution for this in general. (A very patient font designer could, in principle, design ligatures for the character paired with many other characters to give a few extra pixels, but I don't think that would be especially effective.)

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy Feel free to write an answer.

Comment: Everything aside, why use the ellipsis character when you can simply hit the dot button three times?

Comment: @dorukayhan I use a speech recognition program, and it outputs an ellipsis character whenever I say "ellipsis". (which is quite faster than saying three times dots, even though I could define a voice command for that purpose).

Answer (score 7):

This is a bad idea for multiple reasons. The most important one: don't change anything to code blocks! That special unicode character can be intentional. Replacing it for aesthetic reasons is bad. Very bad.

Another problem is that this isn't really a thing to fix. SE uses a monotype font, which is commonly done in code editors for making clear outlines. If SE would fix, they'd either:

- change the character (bad idea as said above)
- switch the font (this is a monotype font problem, so trading that in for a not-equally sized font will made code look ugly and very unclear)
- change the rendering of the single character (still, it is a monotype font, so not much space to fix anything...)

End result: 'fixing' this it will give more problems than it would solve.

Comment: Thanks. (I didn't intend to express any idea on how to fix the issue, I was just trying to give a visual example of a nicer output)

Comment: And it is very understandable for you to ask this, not saying you are doing a bad feature request, but there is much more to it than just three dots.